# How do I calculate mod sum efficiently with query and updates

Tags: data-structures, range, fenwick-tree

Given an array A(say A[1..n]={1,2,3})
now I want two queries:

1) Update(idx,val)   : update value of A[idx]=val

2) int Query(MOD).....

```
int Query(int MOD)  :   // say MOD =2 , so 1%2 +2%2 + 3%2 =2
    int ans=0;
    for i=1 to i=n
        ans+=(A[i]%MOD);
    return ans;
```

I thought of Fenwick Tree with indices as all possible values of MOD but the problem is I don't have constant updates because A[i]%MOD can be different for each A[i]? How Do I Do it efficiently?

Comment: Are the possible values for MOD limited in some way?

Comment: You could cache the results for each different MOD value, and invalidate the cache whenever an update occurs. That assumes, of course, that updates are infrequent in relationship to queries.

Comment: say MOD<=10^5 @MattTimmermans

Comment: @JimMischel Yes I thought of that but Update will take much time

Comment: @user8517664: Update won't necessarily take a lot of time. All update does is clear the cache. Subsequent queries, though, will be slow because the value isn't cached. It really depends on how many items are in `A`.